# How to HTTP2 on apache2 with mod_GnuTLS?

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, ssl, gnutls

It seems google can't show me any page where those three words stand together (apache2, http2, gnutls), so no big hope anyway.

I have a working HTTPS apache2 server on Debian Stretch, with a let's encrypt certificate.

The configuration is functional with `ssl` and `http2` enabled, and I get the server to offer HTTP2 over HTTPS. ✅

However, when I disable `ssl` and enable `gnutls` — together it won't work —, I only get HTTPS and HTTP/1.1.

Can anyone tell for sure "it should [not] work because…"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First hit when searching for ["mod_http2" "gnutls"](https://www.google.com/search?q="mod_http2"+"gnutls") is the [Changelog from mod_gnutls](https://mod.gnutls.org/browser/mod_gnutls/CHANGELOG) where it clearly states:

> ** Version 0.8.4 (2018-04-13) 
> ...
>   - Support TLS for HTTP/2 connections with mod_http2

According to [this](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libapache2-mod-gnutls) Debian Stretch comes with `mod_gnutls` in version 0.8.2, which is less than 0.8.4 and thus has no support for `mod_http2`. Therefore make sure to use a recent enough version of `mod_http2` and `mod_gnutls`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I missed to catch.